# dojo.xhrget() timeout results in automatic page refresh. How to stop that?

Tags: dojo, timeout

I have code like this - it basically makes AJAx call and then displays the dialog box. When the response is received for the AJAX call dialog box will be updated with the result or error. It works fine until here. But, if the timeout occurs for AJAX call, error message is shown in the dialog box and then it immediately refreshes the page (and it is not firing close action of the dialog). Not sure how to stop automatic refresh of the page in case of timeout. Any suggestions or inputs are highly appreciated. Thanks.

```
        var mainNode = dojo.create("div",{id:"mainNode"});

        var brNode = dojo.create("div",{innerHTML:"<br><br>"})              
        var resultNode = dojo.create("div", {id:"resultNode",innerHTML:"Copying..."});
        var infoNode = dojo.create("div", {id:"infoNode"});

        dojo.style(mainNode, "width","700px");
        dojo.style(mainNode, "height","auto");
        mainNode.appendChild(infoNode);
        mainNode.appendChild(brNode);
        mainNode.appendChild(resultNode);


        var timeoutStr = nlsVar.FILEPUB_EXTENSION.TIMEOUT;
        var timeoutVal = parseInt(timeoutStr);
        console.log('timeout value ' + timeoutVal);
        dojo.xhrGet({ 
            // The following URL must match that used to test the server.
            url: "/BpFilePublisher/bpfilepub", 
            handleAs: "json",
            timeout: timeoutVal, // Time in milliseconds
            preventCache: true,

            // The LOAD function will be called on a successful response.
            load: function(response, ioArgs) { //
                  var str = json.jsonBeanStringify(response);
                  var infoNode = dojo.byId("infoNode");
                  infoNode.innerHTML = response[0].info;
                  var resultNode = dojo.byId("resultNode");
                  resultNode.innerHTML = response[0].result; 
                  dojo.style(resultNode, "backgroundColor", "lightgreen");
                  dojo.style(resultNode, "border", "1px green");
            },

            // The ERROR function will be called in an error case.
            error: function(error, ioArgs) { // 
                 console.log('error' + error);
                 console.log('error.responseText' + error.responseText);
                 var resultNode = dojo.byId("resultNode");              
                 if ( error.responseText)
                   resultNode.innerHTML = error.responseText;
                 else {
                   resultNode.innerHTML = 'Timeout occured. Please try again';
                   isTimeout = true;
                   }
                  dojo.style(resultNode, "backgroundColor", "red"); 
                  dojo.style(resultNode, "border", "1px");      

              },

            // Input parameters to the servlet
            content: {fileName: fileName, fileId: fileId, srcCommUuid: srcCommId, bpCommId: bpCommUuid, action:action }
        });

        var dialogBundle = lconn.core.DialogUtil.popupForm(
            nlsVar.FILEPUB_EXTENSION.COPYINTERNAL_DIALOG_TITLE,
            mainNode,
            '',
            nlsVar.FILEPUB_EXTENSION.CANCEL_BUTTON_TITLE,
            function() { 

            },
            function() {
                 dialogBundle.hide();
                 location.reload();
            }
        );

        dojo.addClass(dialogBundle._dialog.lotusSubmitNode, "lotusHidden");
        dojo.addClass(dialogBundle._dialog.lotusBorderNode, "mydialog");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

An AJAX timout is not supposed to result in a page refresh. Perhaps there is something else causing this. Maybe `location.reload()` ?